# How to create a long red line (limit line) in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using `MPAndroidChart` library version `2.2.4`. My requirement is I want to set three marker lines in a `BarChart` with values "Minimum", "Average" and "Maximum" like in the image below, but I can't find any solution for this.

[image: a line chart with three red limit lines labelled max, average, and min]

Answer (score 21):

In MPAndroidChart 3.x.x what you are asking for is called a [`LimitLine`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/a3c1fe6bbf7d48b79b42b3a447f946af850d86f0/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/LimitLine.java)

There is an example of how to consume it in the [sample project](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/a3c1fe6bbf7d48b79b42b3a447f946af850d86f0/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity1.java):

```
    LimitLine ll1 = new LimitLine(150f, "Upper Limit");
    ll1.setLineWidth(4f);
    ll1.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
    ll1.setLabelPosition(LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_TOP);
    ll1.setTextSize(10f);
    ll1.setTypeface(tf);


    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines(); // reset all limit lines to avoid overlapping lines
    leftAxis.addLimitLine(ll1);
```

If you require a customized limit line, you will have to look at the instructions in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083802/custom-view-of-limit-line-in-mpandroidchart)

Comment: Thanks its looking good 
here i add one more property for identifying the line with custom color use this
`ll1.setLineColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
`

Comment: How to fill color for area between LowerLimitLine and UpperLimitLine ?