# How to create a custom limit line label in candlestick chart using ios-charts library?

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I'm using a "Charts" library for drawing candlestick charts in my iOS app.

How can I have labels for limit lines like on the image below?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8xFa.png)

As far as I understand I have to create a custom renderer for Y axis and override methods for drawing limit lines and/or Y axis labels. 
So far I managed to achieve this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7ecv.png), but the label is not attached to the right end of the limit line and has a static position which means if I zoom or drag the chart it doesn't move correctly with the other labels on the axis. As of now Y labels are generated automatically by the chart.

I tried to follow this example but it didn't work for me: [Custom view of Limit Line in MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083802/custom-view-of-limit-line-in-mpandroidchart)

Could you tell me what exactly should I do to make limit line and it's label look like on the example image?
Would be nice to have a detailed explanation + code since I'm new to iOS programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after some tinkering with the Y axis renderer I managed to achieve this look and behaviour.

So in order to get that look you would have to:

1. Disable the default limit line label by calling `setDrawLabelsEnabled()` with the parameter set to `false`
2. Make changes to the YAxisRenderer.swift. The key is to slightly redo the `internal func drawYLabels(...)` to draw additional labels for each limit line. See the code below.
3. Add the offsets to the X and Y axes (both of them) like this:

   `chart.leftAxis.xOffset = 10.0
    chart.leftAxis.yOffset = 0.0`

Here's a code snippet of the new `internal func drawYLabels(...)` method:

```
internal func drawYLabels(
        context: CGContext,
        fixedPosition: CGFloat,
        positions: [CGPoint],
        offset: CGFloat,
        textAlign: NSTextAlignment)
    {
        guard
            let yAxis = self.axis as? YAxis
            else { return }

        let labelFont = yAxis.labelFont
        let labelTextColor = yAxis.labelTextColor

        let from = yAxis.isDrawBottomYLabelEntryEnabled ? 0 : 1
        let to = yAxis.isDrawTopYLabelEntryEnabled ? yAxis.entryCount : (yAxis.entryCount - 1)

        for i in stride(from: from, to: to, by: 1)
        {
            let text = yAxis.getFormattedLabel(i)

            ChartUtils.drawText(
                context: context,
                text: "   " + text + "   ",     // Adding some spaces infront and after the label to make some additional space for the bigger "limit line" labels
                point: CGPoint(x: fixedPosition, y: positions[i].y + offset),
                align: textAlign,
                attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: labelFont, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: labelTextColor])


        }

        // This is where we start to draw labels for limit lines
        let myTransformer = self.transformer

        for line in yAxis.limitLines {

            let point = myTransformer!.pixelForValues(x: 0.0, y: line.limit)

            let text = ("  " + line.label + "  ") as NSString       // Adding some spaces to the label in order to make some additional space for the label
            let size = text.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: labelFont, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray, NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.green])
            var labelPoint: CGPoint?

            // Drawing the triangle in front of the custom label
            let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
            if yAxis.axisDependency == .right {
                labelPoint = CGPoint(x: fixedPosition + (size.height * 0.3), y: point.y - (size.height / 2))

                if textAlign == .center
                {
                    labelPoint!.x -= size.width / 2.0
                }
                else if textAlign == .right
                {
                    labelPoint!.x -= size.width
                }



                trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: labelPoint!.x - size.height * 0.375, y: labelPoint!.y + (size.height / 2)))
                trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: labelPoint!.x, y: labelPoint!.y + (size.height * 0.78)))
                trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: labelPoint!.x, y: labelPoint!.y + (size.height * 0.22)))

            } else {

                labelPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: point.y - (size.height / 2))

                trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: labelPoint!.x + size.width * 1.175, y: labelPoint!.y + (size.height / 2)))
                trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: labelPoint!.x + size.width, y: labelPoint!.y + (size.height * 0.78)))
                trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: labelPoint!.x + size.width, y: labelPoint!.y + (size.height * 0.22)))
            }

            NSUIGraphicsPushContext(context)

            // Drawing the custom label itself
            (text as NSString).draw(at: labelPoint!, withAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: labelFont, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray, NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor: UIColor.green])

            trianglePath.close()

            // Drawing the triangle with the same color as the limit line and it's label
            line.lineColor.setFill()
            trianglePath.fill()

            NSUIGraphicsPopContext()

        }

    }
```

The final result looks like this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhbvR.png)

This implementation is not the cleanest one but at least it worked for me.
Feel free to ask questions if something was unclear in my words.

Comment: Is this works if I want to add Limit Line Label to the centre of the Limit Line on top. Still this code works? If I set the limitLine.yOffset = -30 it is going off the screen. Please help me.